# Saber tipo de objeto almacenado en un array JAVA

Tags: java, array, objeto

!Buenas!

Tengo una duda respecto a saber que **tipo** de dato tengo almacenado en un array de objetos. Dado este código en una prueba que estoy haciendo:

```
    Mamifero [] lista = new Mamifero[8];
    lista[0] = new Leopardo(1,"Leopardo",7,2,5,9,15.6);
    lista[1] = new Leopardo(2,"Leopardo",56,90,1,107,100);
    lista[2]= new Elefante(3,"Elefante",570,200,4,100,"africa");
    lista[3] =new Elefante(4,"Elefante",430,180,2,99,"africa");
    lista[4] =new Elefante(5,"Elefante",270,100,1,101,"africa");
    lista[5] = new Ballena(6,"Ballena",356,90,1,0,"azul");
    lista[6] = new Ballena();
    lista[7] = new Leopardo();
```

Básicamente tengo la clase padre **Mamífero** y de ella heredan pues: **Leopardo**, **Elefante**... etc.

En la clase padre tengo varios métodos, y algunos solo son aplicables en dos subclases. Para ello necesito saber si la **posición 1** tiene almacenado un **Leopardo** por ejemplo.

¿Hay alguna forma de saber esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos formas: Preguntar la clase (usando el método `.getClass()`) o comparar con `instanceof`. En general es mejor práctica el uso de `instanceof` porque es más flexible y si en un futuro quieres añadir más clases a la lista que tienen cierto método no tendrías que modificar el código ya existente:

Imagina que, como comentas, tenemos un método que sólo existe en un par de subclases que extienden `Animal`, digamos que `Leopardo` y `Elefante` pueden andar porque son animales terrestres, mientras que Ballena nada porque es acuática.

Podemos hacer que Leopardo y Elefante, además de ser subclases de Animal, cumplan con la interfaz Terrestre:

```
public interface Terrestre {
   public void andar(int metros);
}

class Leopardo extends Animal implements Terrestre { ... }
```

Cuando quieras llamar a este método podrías tener una lista de clases que cumplan la interfaz:

```
Animal a= new Leopardo(...);
...

if (a.getClass() == Elefante.class || 
    a.getClass() == Leopardo.class) || ...) {
```

O podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (a instanceof Terrestre) {
    ((Terrestre) a).anda(100);
}
```

Porque tendríamos que todas estas condiciones son `true`

```
a instanceof Terrestre
a instanceof Leopardo
a instanceof Animal
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 Class clase = lista[i].getClass();

 System.out.println("El objeto es de tipo " + clase.getName());
```

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta da pistas de una posible solución, es un poco *pobre* porque no la acompañas de ninguna explicación.